# PDFtron - Disable surface pen from writing in document

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, pdftron, pdfnet

On a windows store app project, im using a [PDFtron PDFViewCtrl](http://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/mobile/docs/WinRT/html/T_pdftron_PDF_PDFViewCtrl.htm) to display a pdf document.
I have a part of the screen where the document is displayed, and it is working well.

I would like to know if there is a way to disable surface pen funcionality on this control, because as it is right now, when i pass over document with the pen, it starts drawing lines.

This is my XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="pdfViewer" Background="Transparent" Canvas.ZIndex="111" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border x:Name="PDFViewBorder" Background="White" Grid.Row="0"/>
</Grid>
```

and this is my code behind

```
MyPDFViewCtrl = new pdftron.PDF.PDFViewCtrl();
PDFViewBorder.Child = MyPDFViewCtrl;
docpdf = new pdftron.PDF.PDFDoc(file);
docpdf.InitSecurityHandler();
MyPDFViewCtrl.SetDoc(docpdf);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the PDFViewCtrlTools project, in the Pan tool (Pan.cs), in the PointerPressedHandler method, there is a check if the pointer is a pen
`else if (e.Pointer.PointerDeviceType == PointerDeviceType.Pen)`
This is what causes the inking to happen. You can edit this to change the behaviour.

Comment: Ok ill try that, but from what i understand if i edit that, it will affect all my PDFviewctrl, and i just want to disable that feature on a specific one.